# Salesforce Apex Error 'Apex type not found for element products'

Tags: soap, wsdl, salesforce, apex

I've generated Apex from a WSDL, but when invoking a callout I get the error  'Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element products'. I know it has something to do when I generated the WSDL, but not sure how to fix it or why. Here are the pieces that I believe is causing the problem. I know there are other solutions and I have looked at those, but this seems different because of the type="impl:..."

```
<complexType name="myVData">
    <sequence>
      <element name="products" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns1_VTP"/>
    </sequence>
```

...

```
<complexType name="ArrayOf_tns1_VTP">
        <sequence>
          <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="tns1:VTP"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
```

Anyone got a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found the error if anyone else runs into the same problem. First I found that SOAPUI is a very helpful tool for figuring out what the response should be like.

Second, the generated Apex class from the wsdl was wrong (or wsdl, however you want to look at it) and the apex was looking for products and not item (as shown in the ArrayOf_tns1_VTP complex. I changed the name="item" to name="products" in the wsdl, regenerated the Apex and works now!

Comment: love it when I find my own answers :)